# How to connect different meshes?

Tags: mesh, topology

How should I connect different meshes when sculpting a character?

For example, I made the head and neck, and I want to attach them to the body. If I use the Boolean modifier, then the topology doesn't converge (for example, if the head has more polygons than the body). In this case, only remesh will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the size of the polygons need to be the same? If it does for some reason, you can use the *Remesh* tool, or you can use the *Draw* brush, put its *Strength* at 0, choose the *Dyntopo* detail size, and sculpt. It won't change the shape but it will harmonize the face sizes:

[image]

*Nota Bene:* This technic won't merge the different meshes, only the *Remesh* tool will, but you can still use the merge by distance. But anyway you said that you've used a boolean so you have a unique mesh if I understand correctly.

Comment: Your answer gives me an impression we can use Draw brush to connect different meshes ...

Comment: Oops no, but as he said that he used a boolean, I think his different meshes have merged...